MySQL - Update max value where duplicates occur in separate column
I am currently migrating some media assets to a 3rd party application (3PA), our internal system has the assets logged in the sample data below, however the 3PA requires the SoundRecordingCode be related to the ISRC so I need to run a bulk update statement against 10000's of entries similar to my sample dataset.
Sample dataset:
| Id | SongCode | SoundRecordingCode | ISRC       | ContractId   |
|----|----------|--------------------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | 100      | 201                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 2  | 100      | 202                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 3  | 100      | 203                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 4  | 100      | 204                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 5  | 100      | 205                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 6  | 101      | 206                | ISRC_002   | 43           |
| 7  | 101      | 207                | ISRC_002   | 43           |
| 8  | 102      | 208                | ISRC_003   | 43           |
| 9  | 102      | 209                | ISRC_003   | 43           |
| 10 | 102      | 210                | ISRC_003   | 43           |

I am trying to update the value of SoundRecordingCode to MAX(SoundRecordingCode) where the ISRC is duplicated, therefore i would like the final result to be:
| Id | SongCode | SoundRecordingCode | ISRC       | ContractId   |
|----|----------|--------------------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | 100      | 205                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 2  | 100      | 205                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 3  | 100      | 205                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 4  | 100      | 205                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 5  | 100      | 205                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 6  | 101      | 207                | ISRC_002   | 43           |
| 7  | 101      | 207                | ISRC_002   | 43           |
| 8  | 102      | 210                | ISRC_003   | 43           |
| 9  | 102      | 210                | ISRC_003   | 43           |
| 10 | 102      | 210                | ISRC_003   | 43           |

I am using MySQL
I have tried the following update statement:
    UPDATE digitalassets t1
    JOIN (SELECT Id, MAX(SoundRecordingCode) AS MaxSoundRecordingCode, ISRC
          FROM digitalassets
          WHERE ContractId = 43
          GROUP BY ISRC
          HAVING COUNT(ISRC) > 1) t2 USING(Id)
    SET t1.SoundRecordingCode = t2.MaxSoundRecordingCode;

However this has only resulted in a single row being updated:
| Id | SongCode | SoundRecordingCode | ISRC       | ContractId   |
|----|----------|--------------------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | 100      | 205                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 2  | 100      | 202                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 3  | 100      | 203                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 4  | 100      | 204                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 5  | 100      | 205                | ISRC_001   | 43           |
| 6  | 101      | 207                | ISRC_002   | 43           |
| 7  | 101      | 207                | ISRC_002   | 43           |
| 8  | 102      | 210                | ISRC_003   | 43           |
| 9  | 102      | 209                | ISRC_003   | 43           |
| 10 | 102      | 210                | ISRC_003   | 43           |

Many thanks in advance.

t2 USING(Id) - so only 1 row to joined (per soundrecordincode)..you should probably be grouping and joining on songcode. btw where does  9  | 102      | 209  come from is it a transcription error?

The joining column should be the same column you're grouping on in the subquery.
UPDATE digitalassets t1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(SoundRecordingCode) AS MaxSoundRecordingCode, ISRC
      FROM digitalassets
      WHERE ContractId = 43
      GROUP BY ISRC
      HAVING COUNT(ISRC) > 1) t2 USING(ISRC)
SET t1.SoundRecordingCode = t2.MaxSoundRecordingCode;

If you had the SQL mode only_full_group_by enabled, which has been the default since MySQL 5.7, you would have gotten an error from your query.

It is necessary to calculate the maximum value SoundRecordingCode by ISRC.
This calculation differs for MySql 8.0 and 5.5-5.7.
See example
UPDATE digitalassets t1
 JOIN (SELECT Id
        ,ISRC
        ,MAX(SoundRecordingCode)over(partition by ISRC) AS MaxSoundRecordingCode
      -- for MySql 5.5-5.7 use
      --,(select MAX(SoundRecordingCode) FROM digitalassets d2 
      --  where d2.ISRC=d1.ISRC) AS MaxSoundRecordingCode
       FROM digitalassets
       WHERE ContractId = 43
       ) t2 USING(Id)
    SET t1.SoundRecordingCode = t2.MaxSoundRecordingCode;

Result



Id
SongCode
SoundRecordingCode
ISRC
ContractId




1
100
205
ISRC_001
43


2
100
205
ISRC_001
43


3
100
205
ISRC_001
43


4
100
205
ISRC_001
43


5
100
205
ISRC_001
43


6
101
207
ISRC_002
43


7
101
207
ISRC_002
43


8
102
210
ISRC_003
43


9
102
210
ISRC_003
43


10
102
210
ISRC_003
43



example

Have I offended someone? I apologize.
